# When is the semicolon required in Razor syntax?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, syntax

In one of my web MVC3 sites, I'm seeing a semicolon at the bottom of the page.

Are semicolons required on `@using some.Library.Namespace;` statements?

Comment: No, semicolons are not needed in Razor `@using` statements... but it doesn't write the semicolon to the response if you write `@using some.Library.Namespace;` so something else is outputting your extra semicolon

Comment: @nemesv: `Html.DropDownList(...);` is also allowed even though it is not required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two rules for semicolons:

1. **Inside a code block, each complete code statement must end with a semicolon.**

   ```html
   <!-- Single-statement block -->
   @{ var theMonth = DateTime.Now.Month; }

   <!-- Multi-statement block -->
   @{
       var outsideTemp = 79;
       var weatherMessage = "Hello, it is " + outsideTemp + " degrees.";
   }
   ```
2. **Inline expressions don't end with a semicolon.**

   ```html
   <!-- Inline expression, so no semicolon -->
   <p>Today's weather: @weatherMessage</p>
   ```

#### Further Reading

- [Introduction to Using the Razor Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c)
- [Razor Syntax Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0)